# How can I clone a MongoDB database in a script?

Tags: mongodb, bash, scripting

I'm a newbie to mongo, and I've written the following script to clone a database in Mongo:

```
echo 'Enter db to clone: '
read dbToCopy
echo 'Enter name for cloned db'
read newDbName
dumpUri="mongodb://$un:$pw@$ip:$port/$dbToCopy?authSource=test"
restoreUri="mongodb://$un:$pw@$ip:$port/$newDbName?authSource=test"
mongodump --uri=$dumpUri --archive|mongorestore --uri="$restoreUri" --archive
```

I'm getting the below output & error, and can't find any information online. Any ideas, or leads that I could follow?

````
2020-02-20T15:28:01.592-0800    writing *****.Stacks to archive on stdout
2020-02-20T15:28:01.594-0800    writing *****.Queues to archive on stdout
2020-02-20T15:28:01.596-0800    writing *****.LFRs to archive on stdout
2020-02-20T15:28:01.624-0800    Failed: archive writer: error writing data for collection ***** to disk: error reading collection: Failed to parse: { find: "Nodes", skip: 0, snapshot: true, $readPreference: { mode: "secondaryPreferred" }, $db: ***** }. Unrecognized field 'snapshot'. / Mux ending but selectCases still open 4
2020-02-20T15:28:01.641-0800    preparing collections to restore from
2020-02-20T15:28:01.695-0800    reading metadata for *****.Nodes from archive on stdin
2020-02-20T15:28:01.696-0800    restoring *****.Nodes from archive on stdin
2020-02-20T15:28:01.717-0800    no indexes to restore
2020-02-20T15:28:01.718-0800    finished restoring *****.Nodes (0 documents)
2020-02-20T15:28:01.719-0800    done
2020-02-20T15:28:01.719-0800    Failed: error demultiplexing archive; archive finished before all collections were seen (*****.LFRs)```
````

Comment: Since it is related to database administration suggest to post in [https://dba.stackexchange.com/]

Answer (score 0):

The MongoDB docs state:

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongorestore/#copy-clone-a-database

```
mongodump --archive --db=test | mongorestore --archive  --nsFrom='test.*' --nsTo='examples.*'
```

Therefore, try the following:

```
mongodump --uri=$dumpUri --archive|mongorestore --uri="$restoreUri" --archive --nsFrom "$dbToCopy.*" --nsTo "$newDbName.*"
```

Failing that, attempt to mongodump the files to disk and restore from them files.

Comment: I'm still getting the `Failed: error demultiplexing archive; archive finished before all collections were seen` error